# how to write files into resources correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have to download some files from other website while using Spring Boot, and i use

```
FileOutputStream out = (new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(
"src/main/resources/static/img/" + filename)));
```

But after compilation, the file structure has been changed. And the application won't run normally, so I thought this is not a correct way to save files.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Usually your `src` is not deployed - maybe you want to write to below your `classpath` ?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: I have tried this before, however it will throw a java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: You should show what you have tried

Comment: Hmm, I changed path as "resources/static/img/", "static/img/" and "classpath:static/img/", but none of these works :(